# Inserting records in CRM 2011 using SSIS

Tags: foreign-keys, dynamics-crm-2011, primary-key, guid, ssis

I am working on a SSIS (2012) package that collects data from our till system to staging area and from staging area to CRM 2011 (on-premise | Roll up 11).

In CRM we have contact entity and order entity. These two entity are related via a guid called contactid(PK in contact) and customerid(FK in order).

when i insert new order in to CRM how do I ensure that the guid is created to associate that order to either a new contact or already existing contact?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming since you're using SSIS your doing straight SQL inserts? If so, this is not supported.  Ideally you'd be using the SDK, and in that case, you can set the GUID manually before actually creating the record, although the Contact Id still has to exist when creating the Order.

So you'll want to grab all of your existing Contacts up front, then determine for each order, if the contact exists or not.  If it does, just set the customerId when you create the order and you're all set.  If it doesn't, you'll need to create the Contact (potentially assigning it an Id), and then setting the customerId when you create the order.

Comment: Thanks Daryl, All our Sales/Orders will have customerids and for all these customerid, there will be a contact. That makes my life a little easier. I am also dropping the idea of direct insert and using SSIS (c# scripting) to insert/update records using SDK. I hope it can handle high volume of data!!

Comment: Just to update, I am now using SSIS with some C# to insert/update/delete records in CRM using web service. Yes, I had to learn C# from scratch but it was totally worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I would echo what Daryl has said in that SQL inserts are not supported and generally a bad idea. However there is a solution, a company called Kingsway Soft make a SSIS component that allows you to read and write into CRM using the web services. The best part of it is that it is free if you don't want to run it using SQL agent. Even if you do want to schedule it the cost is very small for such an excellent product.

You can download it from here

http://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I will have a look in to this but to be honest my company want to bring everything in-house. We are using Scribe at the moment and it is turning out to be a giant pain.